# jQuery Click Event on TD elements without triggering on the Nested Table TD elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table where the rows are dynamically removed and added via jQuery. There are supposed to be click event handlers on the `td > ul` elements and there is the possibility of a sub-table within a `td` element. My problem is that I can not figure out how to establish a listener on the parent table's `td > ul` elements without triggering a click on the nested table's `td > ul` elements. I have tried the following statements using `jQuery.on()`.

HTML

```
<table class="click-me">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul><li>click</li></ul>
            </td>
            <td>dummy td
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td { border: 1px solid; margin: 20px; padding: 20px; }

.new { background-color: yellow; }
```

Javascript

```
$("table.click-me > tbody").on("click", "tr:first-child > td > ul > li", function()
{
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class=\"new\"><td><ul><li>click (new)</li></ul></td><td><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li>click</li></ul></td><td>dummy td</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>")
});

$("table.click-me").on("click", "tbody > tr > td > ul > li", function()
{
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class=\"new\"><td><ul><li>click (new)</li></ul></td><td><table class=\"\"><tbody><tr><td><ul><li>click</li></ul></td><td>dummy td</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>")
}); //works on ALL children elements, even the sub-table. Not the desired results
```

As always, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give it a starting point

Start from table.click-me > tbody > then get first tr only

```
$("table.click-me").on("click", "tbody:first > tr > td > ul > li", function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class=\"new\"><td><ul><li>click (new)</li></ul></td><td><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li>click</li></ul></td><td>dummy td</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wgRb5/1/

Comment: This statement works when I change the jQuery to `$("table.click-me").on("click", "tbody:first > tr > td > ul > li ", function() { . . . });` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/wgRb5/2/)

Comment: I will accept this answer once my edits go through. Thanks for the support on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4tX2/1/)

```
$("table.click-me > tbody > tr:first-child > td > ul > li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class=\"new\"><td><ul><li>click (new)</li></ul></td><td><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li>click</li></ul></td><td>dummy td</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>")
});    ​
```

Or maybe you want [This One](http://jsfiddle.net/SgNbP/)

```
$("table.click-me > tbody > tr > td > ul > li").live("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class=\"new\"><td><ul><li>click (new)</li></ul></td><td><table><tbody><tr><td><ul><li>click</li></ul></td><td>dummy td</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>")
});

​
```

Comment: @SD, the first one, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4tX2/1/), does not work as intended. The new row created with the sub-table does not have the click event enabled.

Comment: @SD, as for the other example, [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depreciated and I would like to use the `.on` jQuery functionality.